# Trying to loop through JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am creating a dictionary app in React, I have loaded in the JSON dictionary which looks like this:

```
{
"DIPLOBLASTIC": "Characterizing the ovum when it has two primary germinallayers.",
"DEFIGURE": "To delineate. [Obs.]These two stones as they are here defigured. Weever.",
"LOMBARD": "Of or pertaining to Lombardy, or the inhabitants of Lombardy.",
"BAHAISM": "The religious tenets or practices of the Bahais.",
"FUMERELL": "See Femerell."
}
```

The user enters a word in the input field and the value is then passed into the following function to search for a matching key in the JSON. Matching words are then pushed into an array of results with their respective value.

```
handleSearch: function(term) {
    var term = term;
    var results = [];
    for (var key in Dictionary) {
        if (Dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (term == Dictionary[key]) {
            results.push(Dictionary[key])
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(results)
},
```

However I am struggling to find a successful way of looping through it to get results. the console is logging an empty array.

Can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: what's the value of term?

Answer (score 0):

You can have better matching by adding a compare function (in example below it is the `compareTerm` function). What I did there is comparing if the term STARTS with the dictionary key, if you want it to be any part of the string you can change it from `=== 0` to `> -1`.

```js
// compare function which needs to be added somewhere
function compareTerm(term, compareTo) {
  var shortenedCompareTo = compareTo
    .split('')
    .slice(0, term.length)
    .join('');

  return term.indexOf(shortenedCompareTo.toLowerCase()) === 0;
}

// only changed the compare function
handleSearch: function(term) {
    var results = [];
    for (var key in Dictionary) {
        if (Dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (compareTerm(term, Dictionary[key])) {
              results.push(Dictionary[key])
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(results);
},
```